# Understanding how canvas converts an image to black and white

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

I found this script for converting an image to black and white, which works great, but I was hoping to understand the code a little bit better. I put my questions in the code, in the form of comments.

Can anyone explain in a little more detail what is happening here:

```
function grayscale(src){ //Creates a canvas element with a grayscale version of the color image
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = src;
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); //Are these CTX functions documented somewhere where I can see what parameters they require / what those parameters mean?
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4; //Why is this multiplied by 4?
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3; //Is this getting the average of the values of each channel R G and B, and converting them to BW(?)
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height); 
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The canvas functions are, like most functions, described in [an official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html). Also, [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) is helpful for more "informal" articles. E.g. the `drawImage` function on MDC is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Drawing_images).
2. The `getImageData` function returns an object, which contains an array with the byte data of all pixels. Each pixel is described by 4 bytes: `r`, `g`, `b` and `a`.

   `r`, `g` and `b` are the color components (red, green and blue) and alpha is the opacity. So each pixel uses 4 bytes, and therefore a pixel's data begins at `pixel_index * 4`.
3. Yes, it's averaging the values. Because in the next 3 lines `r`, `g` and `b` are all set to that same value, you'll obtain a gray color for each pixel (because the amount of all 3 components are the same).

   So basically, for all pixels this will hold: `r === g`, `g === b` and thus also `r === b`. Colors for which this holds are grayscale (`0, 0, 0` being black and `255, 255, 255` being white).

Answer (score 9):

```
function grayscale(src){ //Creates a canvas element with a grayscale version of the color image
    //create canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    //get its context
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //create empty image
    var imgObj = new Image();
    //start to load image from src url
    imgObj.src = src;
    //resize canvas up to size image size
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height;
    //draw image on canvas, full canvas API is described here http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    //get array of image pixels
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //run through all the pixels
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            //here is x and y are multiplied by 4 because every pixel is four bytes: red, green, blue, alpha
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4; //Why is this multiplied by 4?
            //compute average value for colors, this will convert it to bw
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            //set values to array
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    //draw pixels according to computed colors
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height); 
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

In this function coefficient equal to 1/3 are used, however the usually used are: 0.3R + 0.59G + 0.11B (http://gimp-savvy.com/BOOK/index.html?node54.html).

Comment: Isn't the image stored still in a full color mode, even it is black-and-white/grayscale? What if I want pure black-and-white canvas that I want to save as black-and-white image (much smaller file size)?