# How to change the sharpness and make a photo black and white using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have designed a basic webpage in HTML which is basically web app to edit the photos online.

Now I am unable to code the program as to how the colour sharpness brightness blurness, making a photo black and white and others haven't been possible.

How do we use HTML and JavaScript to make this work online?

Comment: n != and ... also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you expecting? You can always manually change the pixels in modern browsers...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `<canvas>`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

- Draw image on `<canvas>` using Javascript
- Canvas gives raw pixel access. Run filtering code written in Javascript. Example: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/03/jsimagefx-javascript-image-effects.html
- You can use `<canvas>` in a similar manner in HTML code as `<img>` - both are basically pixel buffers

Note that you cannot access pixel data of images loaded from different origin.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502271/understanding-how-canvas-converts-an-image-to-black-and-white